# EF EntityState.Modified Try Catch Issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a code like this:

```
try
{
    Member member = database.Members.Where(m=>m.ID=1).FirstOrDefault();
    member.Name = "NewMemberName";
    database.Entry(member).State = EntityState.Modified;
    database.SaveChanges();
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
{        
    database.Logs.Add(new Log() { Value=ex.ToString() });
    database.SaveChanges();
}
```

And Entity:

```
[StringLength(5)]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

If the Name String more than 5 it would be error and catch the exception ,but when I add a log then save ,the exception from SaveChange(); still remains,how should I do?(Can't change the schema)

Comment: If `SaveChanges()` throws an exception, why would you expect it to work immediately a moment later?  Don't re-try `SaveChanges()` in the `catch` block.

Comment: sorry didn't notice that,I want to catch the exception and write a log messge to database,so I have to use  database.SaveChanges() after add a log .

Answer (score 1):

> the exception from SaveChange(); still remains

Well, if this throws an exception:

```
database.SaveChanges();
```

Then there's a *pretty good chance* that *this* will also throw an exception:

```
database.SaveChanges();
```

Basically, in your `catch` block you shouldn't be immediately re-trying the operation that just failed a millisecond ago.  Instead, log the failure and handle the exception:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // DO NOT call SaveChanges() here.
}
```

Of course, if writing to the database is failing, then logging to the database is *also* likely to fail.  Suppose for example that the connection string is wrong or the database is down or timing out.  You can't log that.

I recommend using a logging framework (log4net, NLog, etc.) as a separate dependency from your Entity Framework data access layer.  It's a small learning curve, but you end up with a pretty robust logging system that can much more effectively handle problems.  *And* can be easily configured to log to multiple places, so if writing to one error log (the database) fails then you still have another one (a file, for example).

At the very least, if persisting your data context fails, you'll need to log to a *new* data context.  Otherwise the part that failed is still there.

Something structurally more like this:

```
try
{
    using (var database = new DbContext())
    {
        Member member = database.Members.Where(m=>m.ID=1).FirstOrDefault();
        member.Name = "NewMemberName";
        database.Entry(member).State = EntityState.Modified;
        database.SaveChanges();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    using (var database = new DbContext())
    {
        database.Logs.Add(new Log() { Value=ex.ToString() });
        database.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```